# updating a div tag that pulls data from another site, I want that div to auto-refresh without having to reload the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

> I want to update getPrice($url) function every 1sec without manual
>   page refresh

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

> This function getPrice($url) currently refreshes only when i refresh page manually.

```
function getPrice($url)
{
    $decode = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($decode, true);
}

$btcUSD = getPrice('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker');
$btcPrice = $btcUSD ["ticker"]["last"];

$btcDisplay = round($btcPrice, 2);
?>
```

> HTML code begins here.

```
<html>
<title>Coin-Co. | Welcome!</title>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<style>
h1
{
    font-family: "Calibri", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

> This is the div for function getPrice($url)

```
#container
{
    font-family: "Calibri", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    border: 3.8px solid #666666;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 425px;
}

#containerConvert
{
    font-family: "Calibri", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 38px;
    border: 2.9px solid #666666;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 63px;
    width: 497px;
}
#bi , #ci
{
    font-family: "Calibri", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    border: 2.9px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 1.75px;
    height: 48.7px;
    width: 148px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var chart;
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live_btce.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                                 // longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'containerChart',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live feed BTCe 5second-Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            title: {
                text: 'USD',
                margin: 80
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'BTC->USD',
            data: []
        }]
    });        
});

</script>
<center>
<h1><em>BTC|USD</em></h1>

<div id="container"><?php echo $btcDisplay; ?></div></br>

<script>
    function btcConvert(input)
    {if (isNaN(input.value))
         {
           input.value = 0; 
         }
        var price = "<?php echo $btcDisplay; ?>";
        var output = input.value * price;
        var co = document.getElementById('ci');
        ci.value = output.toFixed(2);
    }
        function usdConvert(input)
        {if (isNaN(input.value))
    {
        input.value = 0;
    }
          var price2 = "<?php echo $btcDisplay; ?>";
          var output2 = input.value / price2;
      var co2 = document.getElementById('bi');
      bi.value = output2.toFixed(8);
        }
</script>
<div id="containerConvert">
<input type="text" name="bi" id="bi" onchange="btcConvert(this);" onkeyup="btcConvert(this);" /> BTC =
<input type="text" name="ci" id="ci"  onchange="usdConvert(this);" onkeyup="usdConvert(this);" /> USD 
</div>
<div id="containerChart" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, so what is the problem?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://devzone.co.in/automatically-refresh-html-page-div-specific-time-interval/

Comment: Call relevant method of plugin once data updated `chart.redraw()`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your php code you are missing

```
echo $btcDisplay;
```

and before adding point in javascript parse it as float

```
// add the point
point = parseFloat(point);
chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);
```

Comment: I realize my question is not the clearest, first time posting a question on here. The problem I am facing is, I want my <div id ="container"> to update every second without refreshing the page. It is already getting the data from a website, but I have to manually refresh the page to update the <div id="container">.

Comment: Then just add `$('#container').html(point);` after above lines and it will update div html with your data